# Bootstrap 2.3.2 typeahead trigger ENTER keyCode event when an item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a text input field and I'm using Bootstrap Typeahead to set US State names as its typeahead values. I also have a function `foo`, which takes the event keyCode as input, and adds the text field input value to a list (it's more complex than that, but the details shouldn't be important). The user can input values into this field multiple times, and each time the user inputs a value and presses "enter", `foo` is called and the input field is cleared. What I've noticed is that, if I type a few letters, use the arrow keys to select the value I want, and then press "enter", `foo` gets called with the item and it's added to the list as expected. However, when I type a few letters and then use the mouse to click on the value I want, the correct value gets put into the text field, but `foo` is not called. If the user presses "enter" at this point then `foo` will be called as expected, but I want `foo` to be called as soon as the user clicks the value in the typeahead list.

I have tried two methods so far.

1) Add a `click` event handler to the input as such:

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
  // Call foo() passing it the ENTER event keyCode
})
```

This is obviously problematic because it will be triggered whenever the user clicks the input box, but I just wanted to see if this gets called with the user clicks on a value in the typeahead list. I found that it does NOT, so it seems that Bootstrap Typeahead propagates the `keyup` event to the input box, but not the `click` event. Is that correct, or is something else happening here?

2) Trigger the event using the `updater` method of Bootstrap Typeahead:

```
$('input').typeahead({
  source: stateList,
  updater: function(item) {
    // trigger the 'keyup' event with keyCode 13 (the ENTER keyCode)
    return item;
  }
});
```

This shouldn't work, since the item is returned AFTER the event is triggered. What I would expect to happen here is that whatever the user has entered into the input field already gets added to the list (e.g. if I type "ca" and click on "California", "ca" would get added instead of "California"), but it seems like that isn't happening either, as `foo` still isn't getting called.

The Bootstrap 2 documentation on typeaheads is fairly sparse, and unfortunately I can't upgrade to Bootstrap 3 for this project. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with Bootstrap 2 typeahead?

TL;DR I want an input value to be entered in the text box AND submitted ("enter" key pressed) when I click on a value from the bootstrap typeahead list. It works fine when "enter" is used to select a list item, but not when the mouse is used. How do I make Bootstrap Typeahead add AND submit the value when it is selected with a mouse click?